When click on header of custom tab I got Uncaught Snapshot missing error
In laravel 11 / livewire 3 app I have a tab with headers defined like :
<!-- STAFF USER TAB BLOCK START -->
<div x-data="{ activeTab: {{ $activeTab }} }">
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-full inline-flex flex-wrap justify-center bg-green-100 rounded-[20px] p-1 px-2 mb-6">
            <!-- Button #1 Details-->
            <button
                id="tab-1"
                class="flex-1 text-sm font-medium h-8 px-4 rounded-2xl whitespace-nowrap focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-indigo-300 transition-colors duration-150 ease-in-out"
                :class="activeTab === 1 ? 'bg-green-500 text-slate-900 underline decoration-double' : 'text-slate-800 hover:text-slate-900'"
                @click="activeTab = 1"
            >{!! AppIconFacade::get(IconEnum::Profile ) !!}
                Details
            </button>

            @if($isEdit)
                <!-- Button #2 Permission tab-->
                <button
                    id="tab-2"
                    class="flex-1 text-sm font-medium h-8 px-4 rounded-2xl whitespace-nowrap focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-indigo-300 transition-colors duration-150 ease-in-out"
                    :class="activeTab === 2 ? 'bg-green-500 text-slate-900 underline decoration-double' : 'text-slate-800 hover:text-slate-900'"
                    @click="activeTab = 2">
                    {!! AppIconFacade::get(IconEnum::Permission ) !!}Permissions
                </button>

                <!-- Button #3 - Active Tasks -->
                <button
                    id="tab-3"
                    class="flex-1 text-sm font-medium h-8 px-4 rounded-2xl whitespace-nowrap focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-indigo-300 transition-colors duration-150 ease-in-out"
                    :class="activeTab === 3 ? 'bg-green-500 text-slate-900 underline decoration-double' : 'text-slate-800 hover:text-slate-900'"
                    @click="activeTab = 3">
                    {!! AppIconFacade::get(IconEnum::Task ) !!}Active Tasks
                </button>

                <!-- Button #4 - Social Medias -->
                <button
                    id="tab-4"
                    class="flex-1 text-sm font-medium h-8 px-4 rounded-2xl whitespace-nowrap focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-indigo-300 transition-colors duration-150 ease-in-out"
                    :class="activeTab === 4 ? 'bg-green-500 text-slate-900 underline decoration-double' : 'text-slate-800 hover:text-slate-900 hover:underline'"
                    @click="activeTab = 4">
                    {!! AppIconFacade::get(IconEnum::SocialMedias ) !!}
                    Social Medias TODO
                </button>
            ...

where AppIconFacade::get draws icon. I try to remake it with component like in app/Livewire/Common/EditorTabPanel.php:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Common;

use App\Enums\EditorTabPanelElementEnum;
use App\Enums\IconEnum;
use App\Enums\LayoutTypeEnum;
use Livewire\Component;

class EditorTabPanel extends Component
{
    public int $iteration;
    public EditorTabPanelElementEnum $element;
    public int $order;
    public string $title;
    public IconEnum $iconEnum;
    public bool $active;
    public LayoutTypeEnum $layoutTypeEnum;

    public function mount(
        EditorTabPanelElementEnum $element,
        int $order,
        string $title,
        IconEnum $iconEnum,
        bool $active,
        LayoutTypeEnum $layoutTypeEnum
    ) {
        $this->element = $element;
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->iconEnum = $iconEnum;
        $this->active = $active;
        $this->layoutTypeEnum = $layoutTypeEnum;
    }

    /* User changed Active Tab */
    public function clickActiveTab($order)
    {
        $this->dispatch('activeTabChanged', $order);

    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.common.editor-tab-panel');
    }
}

and blade view resources/views/livewire/common/editor-tab-panel.blade.php, where I try to use similar html :
<div>
    @if($element === EditorTabPanelElementEnum::HEADER_BUTTON)
        <button
            id="tab-{{ $order }}"
            class="flex-1 text-sm font-medium h-8 px-4 rounded-2xl whitespace-nowrap focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-indigo-300 transition-colors duration-150 ease-in-out"
            :class="activeTab === {{ $order }} ? 'bg-green-500 text-slate-900 underline decoration-double' : 'text-slate-800 hover:text-slate-900 hover:underline'"
            wire:click="clickActiveTab({{ $order }})">
            {!! AppIconFacade::get($iconEnum ) !!}
            {{ $title }}
        </button>

    @endif
</div>

and calling this component :
<livewire:common.editor-tab-panel
    :element="EditorTabPanelElementEnum::HEADER_BUTTON"
    :order="4" :title="'Social Medias'" :iconEnum="IconEnum::SocialMedias"
    :active="$activeTab === 4" :layoutTypeEnum="App\Enums\LayoutTypeEnum::ADMIN"
    wire:key="'socialMediasTab'"  />

But I got error :
livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:4493 Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id: UPSIvyEIdzmCAL3zY7kx

and my tab is broken at all
Reading docs at https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/troubleshooting#adding-wirekey
I tried to use alternative syntax :
@livewire('common.editor-tab-panel', [
    'element' => EditorTabPanelElementEnum::HEADER_BUTTON,
    'order' => 4, 'title' => 'Social Medias',
    'iconEnum' => IconEnum::SocialMedias, 'active' => $activeTab === 4,
    'layoutTypeEnum' => App\Enums\LayoutTypeEnum::ADMIN
], key('socialMediasTab') )

                    

But got the same error on click.
What is wrong in my code and how to fix it ?
